# wxDateTime ParseFormat() for milliseconds

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I've been trying to use the wxWidgets wxDateTime::ParseFormat() but want to be able to parse down to millisecond resolution. It seems, from what I've read, that it can only parse down to seconds. Can anyone recommend a way around this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `%l` format specifier should work:

```
dt.ParseFormat("12:34:56.789", "%H:%M:%S.%l")
```

Where did you read that it didn't?

Comment: Thanks for answering VZ. I looked at an online doc (http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxdatetime.html#wxdatetimeparseformat) and then the doc for strptime, which the wx doc says it uses where available. Looked up strptime ( http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html) and couldn't see any mention of milli seconds?

Comment: ah just had another look and it also refers to strftime. The help on that does have a milliseconds format. Let me try it and get back to you, thanks :)